# Most efficient container for uint16_t to uint16_t map

Tags: c++, performance, dictionary

I am developing program for very processing power limited machine where I want to map `uint16_t` keys to `uint16_t` values.

I am currently using `std::map` use non-safe reading:

```
std::map<uint16_t, uint16_t> m;
//fill m only once

while(true){
    auto x = m[y];
}
```

The performance is still non-acceptable for the requirements. Is there a better solution in term of execution speed?

**Edit:**
Some information:

- Total number of items is less than 500
- Insertion is done only once
- Querying values is done more than 250 times / sec
- Keys and values are unique
- Ram is very limited, overall ram is 512KB, free ram for this part of code is less than 50KB
- 100 MHz single core processor

Comment: Have you tried `std::unordered_map`?

Comment: I think more information about the task at hand and restrictions would help.

Comment: Which constraints are required for the container?

Comment: `uint16_t` can hold values 0..65535, so why not just use a fixed array where the keys are the indexes? `uint16_t m[65535]; ... uint16_t y = ...; auto x = m[y];` Such an array would take up only 128K of memory at most.

Comment: How many items? I once did some optimization work and found that for 10 items or less, with small keys (like integers) a simple linear search was faster than maps, unordered maps or binary search. Just start at the front and search until the end or you find it. Don't even keep a length value, just always search the 10 items and fill unused slots with zeros or -1 or whatever. With the fixed size array and the right compiler (and CPU obviously) you can even get that unrolled and vectorized for you.

Comment: You need to provide information about the distribution and size of the data.

Comment: For 500 elements I would start with a plain array and do a linear search.  Cache efficiency can greatly outweigh algorithmic complexity.  If that proves to slow then I would look at your data.  Do you know what the 500 or so values will be?  If so you could come up with a perfect hash for them and store in an array and access through a hashed index. If not then `std::unordered_map` might be faster than your `std::map` solution.

Comment: Use a sorted array and do binary search.

Comment: Why are you even bothering to map the data from one value to another?  Why not just use the original and not have to translate it?

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestion. std::unordered_map results in lower performance than std::map

Comment: @NathanOliver I will try to find perfect hash function, it seems the most feasible solution. Thanks!

Comment: People can provide the best solution it they will know what exact problem your program suppose to solve.

Comment: Is there any law of keys disribution?

Comment: Does the _very processing power limited machine_ have a name?

Answer (score 3):

Without some more context about your map,

if you intend to use a lot of keys, a big array like suggested before would be easy enough to handle since there wouldn't be collisions, but if you're not going to use all the memory, it might be wasteful.

if you intend to use a fair amount of data, but not enough that there'd be too many hash collisions, std::unordered_map has amortized O(1) lookups, and if you don't care about the order they're stored in, that could be a good guess.

if you're using not a lot of data and require it to be flexible, std::vector is a good choice

Seeing as all we know is that it's a uin16_t to uint16_t map, there's no one best answer.

Answer (score 3):

> - Total number of items is less than 500
> - Insertion is done only once

Keep a fixed-size (500) array of key-value pairs plus a "valid items count", if the actual size is known only at runtime; populate it with the data and sort it; then you can simply do a binary search.

Given that the elements are few, depending on the specific processor it may even be more convenient to just do a linear search (perhaps keeping the most used elements first if you happen to have clues about the most frequently looked-up values).

Answer (score 1):

Usually a binary tree (`std::map` which you currently use) provides adequate performance. Your CPU budget must be really small.

A binary search approach probably won't be much faster. A hashtable (`std::unordered_map`) might be a solution.

Just make sure to size it properly so as to avoid rehashing and stay just below 1.0 load factor.

```
std::unordered_map<uint16_t, uint16_t> m(503); // 503 is a prime
m.emplace(123, 234);
m.emplace(2345, 345);

std::cout << m.find(123)->second; // don't use operator[] to avoid creating entries
std::cout << m.find(2345)->second;
```

To check the quality of the hashing function, iterate over all the buckets by calling [`bucket_size()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/bucket_size) and add up anything above 1 (i.e. a collision).